# CSS: Absolute element keeps jumping in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have an absolutely positioned form that appears roughly 200px below where it should be on the page load. If I open up Chrome Dev Tools and disable and re-enable any CSS image it goes where it should be.

This only happens in Google Chrome.

I've tried using the chrome specific CSS rules below but it doesn't work.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

How can I fix this?

Here is the page in question: http://info.iconixx.com/Iconixx-Incentives_imc_incentives1.html

[image: On page load]

[image: Toggling any css rule in chrome dev bar]

Comment: I'd start by stripping most of the heavy-handed layout styling you have on `.form_holder_top` and its child. Your layout is simple enough that you shouldn't have to pound on it that hard. Let the grid do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I added a min-height:232px and the jump is now considerably reduced.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely nested in a different element then your wanting it to be. Make note of the parent element.

Find the element in which that header image is coming from. Likely `<header></header>`

Then make sure that element is defined as `position: relative;`

Within those tags have the relevant mark-up of the element you are trying to position within this area.

```
<header>
   <div id="absoluteelement">
   </div>
</header>
```

Now when you do:

```
#absoluteelement {
   position:absolute;
   top:50px;
   left: 200px;
   // more
}
```

It will be positioned top and left coordinates from the parent element, so top and left from the top and side of `<header>` just double check your code and nesting. Also, make sure you have all widths and heights defined for that area. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really take a look how your markup is structured and consider reformatting it. For 1 the left box in the banner comes after the Form which is on the right. Just like anything else you should build left to right.

```
<div id="banner">
   <div id="left_content"></div>
    <div id="right_form"></div>
</div>
```

You could then....

```
#left_content{ float:left; }
#right_form{ float:right; }
```

This isn't going to give you the exact look you want... but using this approach will really help eliminate thse types of issues to begin with.

Comment: Hope it helps you out. if it did please consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: I added min-height to the jumping container and the issue has been drastically reduced